# Read excel data dynamically in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a excel file in my home directory. I read excel file using below code

```
df <- read_excel("new_sd.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")
```

I wanted to check if we can read the excel file dynamically similar to how we query sql tables dynamically
For example

My excel has below data

```
Col1  Col2
1           A
2           A
3           B
```

While reading above file (`df <- read_excel("new_sd.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")`), can we only import data where Col2 is "A") . So the output would be

```
df 
Col1  Col2
1           A
2           A
```

Comment: Why not just remove the rows you don't want? `subset(df, Col2 == "A")`

Comment: The idea i do not want to load the excel all at once. Say we have 1 lakh records. Its not good to pull all at once. So thought of pulling it as per filter. :) Subseting is done after pulling al data right? Is this what u meant?

Comment: Clear duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360100/read-csv-with-sqldf) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443694/r-read-csv-sql-from-sqldf-is-able-to-successfully-read-one-csv-but-not-another) reopened

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read csv with sqldf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360100/read-csv-with-sqldf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to filter the data while reading and not after you can use `read.csv.sql` from `sqldf` which takes SQL queries to filter but it works only with csv data and cannot read excel files.

If you can convert excel to csv you can use this.

```
library(sqldf)

#Write the csv
#readr::write_csv(mtcars, 'mtcars.csv')

read.csv.sql('mtcars.csv', sql = 'select * from file where cyl = 6')

#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#4 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#5 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#6 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#7 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

Comment: oh nice alternate. Makes sense

Comment: Ronak are you sure this code ````read.csv.sql('mtcars.csv', sql = 'select * from file where cyl = 6')```` filters while reading it self and not that it read all data and then filters?

Comment: That's what their help page says - `?read.csv.sql - Read a file into R filtering it with an sql statement. Only the filtered portion is processed by R so that files larger than R can otherwise handle can be accommodated.`

Comment: Hi Ronak, I tried with your code. But got this error                                                       
 ````filter_data <- read.csv.sql("reviews_data_13.csv", sql = 'select * from file where ID = 208')
Error in connection_import_file(conn@ptr, name, value, sep, eol, skip) : 
  RS_sqlite_import: reviews_data_13.csv line 4 expected 27 columns of data but found 28
Warning message:
In file.remove(dbname) :
  cannot remove file 'C:\Users\VIPRAK~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpI9QDHj\file21d850c3822', reason 'Permission denied````

Comment: Also i replicated your code ````> asd <- read.csv.sql('mtcars.csv', sql = 'select * from file where cyl = 6')
> asd
 [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)````. But returning 0 rows?

Comment: The issue is one of the columns in my dataframe has long string wit comma separated (Great,service across all). Can we overcome this?

Comment: What is the delimiter in that file? I think maybe that requires a new question since this question is more focussed towards filtering the data while reading. It's strange that you get 0 rows while reading `mtcars`. Did you write the csv file correctly with `readr::write_csv(mtcars, 'mtcars.csv')` ? As shown in the answer this works for me without any error.